AWS Lambda with Docker: Read-only File System Error when Using with CrewAI Library
I'm working on an AWS Lambda function using Docker, and I'm encountering a read-only file system error when trying to use the crewAI library, which leverages embedchain. My goal is to ensure all write operations are directed to the /tmp directory, as it's the only writable directory in Lambda.
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12

RUN microdnf install -y gcc gcc-c++ 


COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY .env ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}


COPY *.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}


CMD [ "app.handler" ]

Lambda Handler (app.py):
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

# Ensure configuration directories use /tmp
os.environ["CONFIG_DIR"] = "/tmp/config_dir"


os.makedirs(os.environ["CONFIG_DIR"], exist_ok=True)

def handler(event, context):
    # INvoke the crew
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'Hello from Lambda!'
    }


CrewAI Initialization:
I tried to inherit and force redirect to /tmp folder but that didn't work either.
from crewai import Crew

# Custom CrewAI setup that uses /tmp for configuration
class MyCrewApp(Crew):
    def __init__(self):
        config_dir = os.getenv('CONFIG_DIR', '/tmp/config_dir')
        os.makedirs(config_dir, exist_ok=True)
        super().__init__(config_dir=config_dir)


Error Message:
When I deploy and invoke my Lambda function, I get the following error
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'",
  "errorType": "OSError",
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py\", line 90, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1387, in _gcd_import\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1360, in _find_and_load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 935, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 995, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 3, in <module>\n    from crew import PTECrew\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/crew.py\", line 1, in <module>\n    from crewai import Crew\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/crewai/__init__.py\", line 1, in <module>\n    from crewai.agent import Agent\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/crewai/agent.py\", line 23, in <module>\n    from crewai.agents import CacheHandler, CrewAgentExecutor, CrewAgentParser, ToolsHandler\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/crewai/agents/__init__.py\", line 2, in <module>\n    from .executor import CrewAgentExecutor\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/crewai/agents/executor.py\", line 16, in <module>\n    from crewai.memory.entity.entity_memory_item import EntityMemoryItem\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/crewai/memory/__init__.py\", line 1, in <module>\n    from .entity.entity_memory import EntityMemory\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/crewai/memory/entity/entity_memory.py\", line 3, in <module>\n    from crewai.memory.storage.rag_storage import RAGStorage\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/crewai/memory/storage/rag_storage.py\", line 7, in <module>\n    from embedchain import App\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/embedchain/__init__.py\", line 10, in <module>\n    Client.setup()\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/embedchain/client.py\", line 44, in setup\n    os.makedirs(CONFIG_DIR, exist_ok=True)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen os>\", line 215, in makedirs\n",
    "  File \"<frozen os>\", line 225, in makedirs\n"
  ]
}


I've ensured that the CONFIG_DIR is set to /tmp/config_dir and that the directory is created if it does not exist. Despite these changes, the error persists, indicating attempts to write to a read-only file system. What am I missing? How can I ensure all write operations are directed to the /tmp directory in an AWS Lambda environment using Docker?
NOTE* THIS WORKS Locally though

add an environment variable HOME with value as /tmp

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The easy solution is to set the environment variable HOME to /tmp on your Lambda function.
The embedchain package depends on the mem0ai package (mem0ai = "^0.0.20") that attempts to create its current working directory in the user's home directory, which is not allowed in AWS Lambda environment.
This issue has been resolved in the mem0ai package recently with version 0.1.3 and upwards, which lets you set the MEM0_DIR to overcome the limitation in Lambda environments. However, embedchain has not yet been updated to use the version of mem0ai that fixed this.
This is the offending code in the mem0ai package prior to the fix:
home_dir = os.path.expanduser("~")
mem0_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, ".mem0")
os.makedirs(mem0_dir, exist_ok=True)

Setting the HOME environment variable to /tmp causes the code home_dir = os.path.expanduser("~") to resolve to /tmp instead of the Lambda user's home directory.
Note that, while this should address the issue, there is a small chance that this could cause other places in your code (or the dependencies) that rely on the user's home directory to work correctly. Hope this helps.
